Gradio How to add user avatar in chat interface
I have a very basic code for Gradio chat interface, how can i add user avatar in Gradio chat interface
import gradio as gr
import random
import time

with gr.Blocks(theme=gr.themes.Soft()) as demo:
    chatbot = gr.Chatbot()
    msg = gr.Textbox()
    clear = gr.ClearButton([msg, chatbot])

    def respond(message, chat_history):
        bot_message = random.choice(["How are you?", "I love you", "I'm very hungry"])
        chat_history.append((message, bot_message))
        time.sleep(1)
        return "", chat_history

    msg.submit(respond, [msg, chatbot], [msg, chatbot])

demo.launch()


Two things to add: the order of the images you provide via avatar_images is fixed. You may also need to define the path where the images are located via the gr.set_static_paths so that gradio can access them, ie:
gr.set_static_paths(paths=["assets/"])

And then you provide the images as this:
(...)
chatbot = gr.Chatbot(
    avatar_images='assets/avatar_human.PNG','assets/avatar_AI.PNG'),
    (...)


You have to pass avatar_images to the Chatbot class
import gradio as gr
import random
import time

with gr.Blocks(theme=gr.themes.Soft()) as demo:
    chatbot = gr.Chatbot(avatar_images=["system_avatar.png", "user_avatar.png"])
    msg = gr.Textbox()
    clear = gr.ClearButton([msg, chatbot])

    def respond(message, chat_history):
        bot_message = random.choice(["How are you?", "I love you", "I'm very hungry"])
        chat_history.append((message, bot_message))
        time.sleep(1)
        return "", chat_history

    msg.submit(respond, [msg, chatbot], [msg, chatbot])

demo.launch()

